# Splitting audio signal to frames from memory stream resp. byte array [C#]

Tags: c#, audio, stream, memorystream

I am trying to implement VAD (Voice Activity Detection) algorithm in c# because I did not find any suitable library for this purpose.
Im not working with wave files but only with memory streams just like this:

```
        NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter waveWriter;

        Stream s1 = new MemoryStream();
        WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
        waveSource.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);

        waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
        waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(s1, waveSource.WaveFormat);

        waveSource.StartRecording();
        Console.ReadLine();
        waveSource.StopRecording();
        s1.Position = 0;
        var bytes = streamToArray(s1);
```

Im gonna follow this [tutorial](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.176.6740&rep=rep1&type=pdf) where the first step is to split input signal to 10ms frames. I know how to do this from file input, but how can I perform similar action with array of bytes? 
Thanks for your answer!

Update:

I tested these methods:

1.

```
short[] sdata = new short[(int)Math.Ceiling(bytes.Length / 2.0)]; 
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, sdata, 0, bytes.Length);
```

2.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
            {
                var b1 = (short)bytes[i];
                var b2 = (short)bytes[i + 1];
                sListData.Add((short)(b1 | b2 << 8));
            }
```

And when I compared output arrays with the method using Big Endian, then they are all equal. 
So `BlockCopy`does the job but only when BE is appropiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this it what you mean but:
Assuming audio stream parameters of 16kbp, 16bit per sample, single channel, it's a very quick calculation that if 16000 samples is one second than 10ms is 16000/100 = 160 samples. Now 16bit is 2 bytes which gives us 160 * 2 = 320 bytes.
So each 320 bytes is 10ms.
You can use Array.Copy - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx to copy  chunk od data to separate array.

Just a bit of code below:

var int8Array = new byte[] { 0x04, 0x02, 0x08, 0xA1 };

```
var int16ArrayLE = new List<short>();
var int16ArrayBE = new List<short>();

for(var i=0;i<int8Array.Length;i+=2) 
{
    var b1 = (short)int8Array[i];
    var b2 = (short)int8Array[i+1];
    int16ArrayLE.Add((short)((b1 << 8) + b2));
    int16ArrayBE.Add((short)(b1 + (b2 << 8)));
}
```

In .net short type is 16bit integer and byte is 8bit integer. Code is a bit explicit for readability. I showed 2 possible conversions - Little Endian and Big Endian. In former the first byte is more significant in latter the second byte. Byte order depends on the stream format, can be either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read that to apply FFT on specific frame its size should be power of 2. So I assume that I could just change 320 bytes to 256 right?

Comment: No you got it wrong. In your case you got a frame of 160 samples 2 bytes each. So firstly you should transform each one byte sample to 2byte value with sth like (x[i] + ((int)x[i+1]) << 8) for each odd i.
Second thing is that if you need to work on 256 samples just work on them. in your case each sample represents 0,0625ms so 256 samples is exactlty 16ms, didn't read the paper you linked but is this enough for the algoritm?

Comment: I did not clearly understand what did u mean by your first statement. 
Simply said I need to split output array of bytes to frames of size which base is 2. So e.g 256. 
I just wanted to know if it is correct way just to split e.g byte[8500] into multiple byte[256] and just ignore remainder if the base array is not dividable by 2.
Btw thanks for your time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok so let me clarify:
1. if you have an array of bytes which represent 16bit audio samples, firstly you need to transform it to array of 2 byte numbers. To do it you need to iterate through the 2*N bytes and put together evvery odd and even byte into a single number. Very important thing is which byte is the most significant - odd or even? Let me give you an example - assuming you have 4 byte array: 0x04 0x02 0x08 0xA1 this actually makes samples either 0x0402 0x08A1 or 0x0204 0xA108.

Comment: 2. After you have array of actual 16bit samples you can take 256 of them and calculat FFT. I've started with 160 samples because you mentioned 10ms chunk which in case of 16kbps sampling makes, well, 160 samples ;)
I suppose that with such high sampling 265 samples is ok, because it represents > 10ms. In case of lower sampling - 8kbps it probably would not be enough.

Comment: I edited my question with update. Could you please give reaction if its proper way? Thank you

Comment: No I don't think it's ok, the method that you use "Copies a specified number of bytes from a source array starting at a particular offset to a destination array starting at a particular offset". What you need to do is convert each 2 bytes to a single 16 bit number. Please read my answer update, especially the difference between LE and BE.

Comment: Yeah, seems like we made update simultaneously.
Thank you very much for helping me. :)

Comment: I found out one more issue about this thing.
most of FFTs take as an argument array of floats. Is it ok if i just convert it to float[] explicitly or do I need to do bit-shifting thing again?

Comment: You might try casting each short type value to float this might work. Btw, you should make sure that the stream you operated on is lineary encoded. Sometime non-linear encoding is used to get better resolution in lower energy values.

Comment: Yeah I did it just like that. Now I might have to normalize array of floats because numbers are just too high. But I think Im gonna create topic on dsp to make sure about my other questions.